# Apply C-specific gcc options to C/C++ mixed library

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++

I have a library with a C++ wrapper around auto-generated C code, built with CMake and gcc.  When I compile it I get these warnings which I would like to inhibit:

```
src/ssp/autogenerated.c: In function ‘x1111’:
src/ssp/autogenerated.c:185:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘x1111’; did you mean ‘x1110’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  185 | x1111();
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I should be able to inhibit these warnings with the `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` [warning option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).  I add that to my CMakeLists.txt like so:

```
file(GLOB SRCS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} src/ssp/*.c src/ssp/*.cpp)
add_library(mylib SHARED ${SRCS})
target_compile_options(mylib PRIVATE "-Wno-implicit-function-declaration")
```

However, there is still a `*.cpp` source in there and so compiling gives me:

```
cc1plus: error: command-line option ‘-Wno-implicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [-Werror]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Is there a way inhibit these warnings?  I'm imagining it might be possible to apply `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` to C sources only or to have it ignored by `g++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the option only to C sources. See [cmake generator expressions:](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)

```
target_compile_options(mylib PRIVATE 
     $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-Wno-implicit-function-declaration>
)
```

Comment: Yes this works!  I had to change `$<LANGUAGE:C>` to `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>`, but it's exactly what I needed.